# Decomposition of a divergent series of positive terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, lebesgue-measure

It is well known that if a series $\sum_na(n)$ with positive terms $a(n)$ converges then for any bijection $f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ ww have that

1. For each $m\in\mathbb{N}$ the series $b(m)=\sum_na(f(m,n))$ converges
2. The series $\sum_m b(m)$ converges and $\sum_m b(m)=\sum_na(n)$.

Suppose now that $\sum_na(n)=\infty$.

**My question is**:  Is it possible to find a bijection$f:\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ such that each $m\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$b(m)=\sum_na(f(m,n))=\infty$$

This question is motivated by a  result in **measure theory** that states that if $\{A_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is collection of measurable subsets of the cube $[0,1]^d$, and $\sum_n|A_n|=\infty$, then one can find translates $F_n=A_n+t_n$ such that
$$\limsup_nF_n=\mathbb{R}^d\qquad\text{a.s}$$
I can prove this for $[0,1]^d$ in place of $\mathbb{R}^d$. So if the answer to my question is in the positive, then from the "cover" for the cube, one can pass to a "cover" of $\mathbb{R}^d$.

---

**Edit:** This is a contraction which I think goes along the lines of Hagen von Eitzen's answer below:

Some initial notation:

For $a\in \mathbb{N}^n$ and $b\in \mathbb{N}^m$ define $a\otimes b$ as the element in $\mathbb{N}^{n+m}$ obtained by concatenation and $a$ and $b$, i.e.
$$ a\otimes b=(a(1),\ldots,a(n),b(1),\ldots,b(n))$$
Similarly, For a sequence  of finite tuples $a^{(k)}\in\mathbb{N}^{n_k}$
$$\bigotimes_ka^{(k)}:=(a^{(1)}(1),\ldots,a^{(1)}(n_1), a^{(2)}(1),\ldots,a^{(2)}(n_2),\ldots)\in\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$$

Construction of partition of divergent series $\sum_na_n$, $a_n>0$.
Define integers $0=n_0< n_1<\ldots n_k<n_k<\ldots$ such that
$$ \sum_{n_{k-1}<j\leq n_k}a(j)\geq1,\qquad k\in\mathbb{N}$$
Define $A^{(k)}=(a_j:n_{k-1}< j\leq n_k)$, $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Let $f:\mathbb{N\times\mathbb N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ any bijection, and   define
$$ b^{(k)}:=\bigotimes_nA^{f(k,n)}$$
The choice of the the blocks in each $A^{(k)}$ implies that $\sum_m b^{(k)}(m)=\infty$.

Comment: Just to be clear --- the bijection $f$ is allowed to depend on the sequence $a$, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. This can easily be described as an algorithmic procedure that partitions $\Bbb N$ into subsets $N_k$, $k\in\Bbb N$ such that $\sum_{n\in N_k}a_n$ diverges.
To do so start with all $N_k=\emptyset$ and $M=1$.
Then for $n=1,2,3,\ldots$, pick the smallest $k$ with $\sum_{i\in N_k}a_i<M$, set $N_k\leftarrow N_k\cup\{n\}$ and $M\leftarrow\max\{M,k\}$. It is clear that $M$ grows to infinity, the $N_k$  form a partition of $\Bbb N$, each $N_k$ obtains infinitely many elements, and the sum of elements of each $N_k$ diverges.

Comment: I was just working on a version of this, with the observation that if you can make TWO complementary divergent subseries, then you're done, because you can split the second one into two more, and so on.

Comment: ...and there's an obvious way to do that: "deal" the items $a(1), a(2), ...$ into two piles, always dealing into the pile whose sum is lower; that gives you two complementary divergent subseries.

Comment: Thanks Hagen von Eitzen, I think I got the gist of it. I wrote an idea that I think goes along the lines of your argument as an edit in my posting (too long perhaps for a comment). I would appreciate if you could review it for sake of sanity.